# Does a file extension for Windows / Unix compatible script exists?

Tags: bash, batch-file, compatibility

Just for curiosity... if I write a script with simple compatible Linux / Windows commands is there a specific extension file I can use? 
(Ex. Shell bourne convention: sh, Windows batch convention: .bat, what extension).

Comment: extensions do nothing to the script, call it whatever you want.

Comment: Also no extension exists because bash and batch are not compatible.

Comment: Thanks| Yes I know this it's just for curiosity :)... well if I only do a list of git clones for example it is compatible, doesn't  :) ?

Comment: If you somehow managed to write a script that COULD be run on both (literally nothing but `echo`s, for example), I suppose you could use the . bat extension and then call it in Linux with `bash script.bat`, because the shell doesn't actually care what the extension is.

Answer (score 1):

No; file name extensions are generally meaningless to a kernel or shell. On Unix they are sometimes used to convey information to a human. Some utilities have *conventions* with respect to extensions, or by default create files with certain extensions (file compressors are in this class).